# Problem Read file with US-Ascii Encoding in Dotnet 5? (Work on Dotnet Fx 4.6.2)

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, ascii

i have a code like this:

```
int fLen = FileSystem.FreeFile();
        FileSystem.FileOpen(fLen, txtFilename.Text, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared, -1);

        tmp = new String(' ', Convert.ToInt32(FileSystem.FileLen(txtFilename.Text)));

        FileSystem.FileGet(fLen, ref tmp, -1, false);
        FileSystem.FileClose(fLen);
```

i have platform dotnet framework 4.6.2, , the variable tmp has result:

```
xƒ{‚{{{{{\u007f{\u007f{~{|x‡x„zzzzzzzzzzzzzz{€{zxƒ{|{z{{{\u007fz‡{z{ƒz‡{z{‚zz{{{\u0081{„{{{}{„{}{|xƒ{{xƒ{|xƒ{{xƒ{zx‡x
```

when i upgrade my winforms to the dotnet 5, the variable tmp has result:

```
x�{�{{{{{\u007f{\u007f{~{|x�x�zzzzzzzzzzzzzz{�{zx�{|{z{{{\u007fz�{z{�z�{z{�zz{{{�{�{{{}{�{}{|x�{{x�{|x�{{x�{zx�x�zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{{x�{|{z{{{\u007fz
```

whats wrong with dotnet 5? is it change the formatting when i read file text?

the original text file is: (i copy paste from notepad)

```
xƒ{‚{{{{{{{~{|x‡x„zzzzzzzzzzzzzz{€{zxƒ{|{z{{{z‡{z{ƒz‡{z{‚zz{{{{„{{{}{„{}{|xƒ{{xƒ{|xƒ{{xƒ
```

i use binaryreader, not working too.

```
            var eee = Encoding.UTF7;            
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        //creating BinaryReader using Stream object
        using BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream, eee);
        var tes = eee.GetString(eee.GetBytes(reader.ReadString()));
```

the encoding is : "US-ASCII"

any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

the complete code from sample BioBridgeSDK:

```
private void btnDecryptAttLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string val1 = "";
        string val2 = "";
        string tmp = "";
        Form4 myForm4 = new Form4();

        int fLen = FileSystem.FreeFile();
        FileSystem.FileOpen(fLen, txtFilename.Text, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared, -1);

        tmp = new String(' ', Convert.ToInt32(FileSystem.FileLen(txtFilename.Text)));

        FileSystem.FileGet(fLen, ref tmp, -1, false);
        FileSystem.FileClose(fLen);

        val1 = tmp;
        string ReadFile = val1;

        int iRead = 10000;
        int iPos = 0;
        String FullData = "";
        String SubData = "";

        while (val1.Length > iPos)
        {
            if ((iPos + iRead) > val1.Length)
                iRead = val1.Length - iPos;

            val2 = "";
            SubData = val1.Substring(iPos, iRead);

            if (axBioBridgeSDKv3lib1.DecryptLog(SubData, ref val2) == 0)
                FullData = FullData + val2;

            iPos = iPos + iRead;
        }

        myForm4.Text1.Text = FullData;
        myForm4.Show();
    }
```

Comment: What is this stuff: `FileSystem.FreeFile()` etc.? This looks like a weird port from VB.Net or VB6 that uses ancient methods. Use .Net methods to save your data. UTF-8 is the default Encoding. `US-ASCII` doesn't exist. `Encoding.ASCII` does. But you need `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: Encoding of the file can't be ASCII because `ƒ` *is not* and ASCII character.

Comment: FileSystem.FreeFile() is from Microsoft.VisualBasic Namespace (i use nuget on dotnet 5), i know is it from VB6, the problem is, i use "Fingertec" machine. i decrypt the log file (attendance log) from the machine, and the workaround from the BioBridge SDK is like that. (use old code maybe). i already email the fingertec support, not reply from them. i just want to read from the attandance log file, not write to files. thanks. alterady try UTF8, UTF7, UTF32, Unicode. nothing works.

Comment: Can you show the byte array (the values of that text file read as binary)? One line could be enough (from the very beginning of a file). BTW, if notepad can read the file *correctly*, maybe it's just using `Encoding.Default` (your local codepage).

Comment: how to show the byte array of the text file? my notepad can read the file correctly. without changing everything.

Comment: sorry, not the correct character, still "BOX" appears on notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the encoding.

e.g.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("path", Encoding.ASCII);
```

or for large files use `StreamReader`.  Don't use `BinaryReader` to read text files

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path", Encoding.ASCII))
{
    string line = "";

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Do something with the line.
    }
}
```

Also, In your binary reader code why are you setting the encoding to UTF-7 ?
`var eee = Encoding.UTF7;`

Comment: not work. i set to utf-7, maybe the us-ascii is 7 bit? based on "https://www.charset.org/charsets/us-ascii"  and i use the sample from "https://www.fingertec.com/developerprogram/sdk.php#"

Comment: the result still have character "?"

Comment: @ChandraArifin ... misinforms in their question of what encoding the file has. There is no way file with `ƒ` can be ASCII text. UTF8 is far more likely... so no reason to suggest encoding that has no way to work with a file in the question. Ideally they would show small part with HEX values... instead of text...

Comment: @ChandraArifin try opening the file with a text editor like Notepad++ and see what encoding it detects

Comment: when open with notepad++, the encoding is ANSI

Answer (score 0):

i already find the solution.

```
var text = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
var text1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(text);
```

thanks for the comment, i find the solution by reading the comment. @jimi
and other comments. thanks.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: Encoding 1252 is Windows-1252 / Western European, not ASCII.